# sailsjs waterline search into two tables

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

sailsjs waterline combined search for name like '%sam%' from one table and product name like '%nike%' from another table and left join for getting data in terms of user. i know there is no left join in mongo but how to achieve this. i am using mongodb.

---

```
var reqData =  req.param('q');
        console.log(reqData);
        // Lookup for records that match the specified criteria
         reqData = '%'+reqData+'%';

        console.log(reqData);
        User.find({ first_name: { 'like': reqData }}).exec(function user(err, user){
                    if (err) return res.json(err);
                    console.log(user);
                    res.json(true);
        }); 
Product.find({ name: { 'like': reqData }}).exec(function user(err, user){
                        if (err) return res.json(err);
                        console.log(user);
                        res.json(true);
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

.find() queries from waterline are async (in fact, all nodeJS/sailsJS tasks are async) which means that you have no guarantees of User.find() returning before Product.find().

You need to do nested queries or use promises using [bluebird](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries#?promises) (default library in sails.js)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve this by enabling async in your sails and use it to combine (join) your data.

Enabling it will be in `/config/globals.js` :

```
async : true
```

And to use the code will be :

```
async.parallel({
    user : function(callback){
       //process user object here
       User.find({ first_name: { 'like': reqData }}).exec(function user(err, user){
           //add return to exit the function
           if (err) return callback(err, null);
           console.log(user);
           return callback(null, user);
       });
    },
    product : function(callback){
        //process product object here
       Product.find({ name: { 'like': reqData }}).exec(function user(err, product){
           if (err) return callback(err, null);
           console.log(product);
           return callback(null, product);
       });             
    }
},
function(err, results){
    // the results array will equal { user : [..], product : [..] } even though
    // the second function had a shorter timeout.
    // you can access the user and product objects by results.user & results.product and do the combine process here
});
```

The above snippet is based on your code example given from question that has been amended to suit the async parallel method.

Comment: SELECT u.name,u.age,p.name,p.brand FROM user u LEFT JOIN product p ON u.id = p.id where u.name like "%xyz%" and p.name like "%xyz%"; 

i want to do this type of query in waterline but due to mongo restriction i am not able to get the accurate result.\